# Speed of loopback interface

Tags: macos, performance, nfs, loopback

I am working now with nfs shares. And I want to connect to localhost with nfs. I have disk that can read/write ~400MB/s but when I connect to nfs on localhost I have only ~110MB/s.

I read that loopback interface do not have restricted speed, and should works as fast as cpu can. So, why I have limit to ~1gbps connection?

MacOS 10.12

Comment: If the `socket` program is available under MaxOS, you can run `socket -sl 8080 -p "cat /dev/zero"` in a terminal (that will send endless zeroes to someone connecting at port 8080), and then run any kind of program that reads from network and displays transfer rates, such as for example `wget localhost:8080`. Note that `wget` writes to disk what it receives, so press Ctrl-C soonish or you'll fill your disk! If the loopback device is **not** the culprit, you should get about a gigabyte per second. Otherwise, you may need to investigate firewall rules. Loopback really only requeues packets.

Comment: That means that even though it never leaves the computer, the TCP stack still has to copy and packetize data, calculate checksums, go through routing (outgoing), and then go through routing (incoming) again. Also it has to actually send ACKs and maintain a window. Which may, if you have a lot of firewall rules, be not entirely a free operation. It should normally still be way fast enough to outperform a solid state disk, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the loopback interface is not the cause of this slowdown, I'm not a OSX expert, but using a recent machine using linux will give you multi gigabytes per second bandwidth.

The problem is probably your configuration of NFS, but if you really need speed you will have a better luck with [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/).